# Pysimplegui bidi support

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use pysimplegui in order to generate Hebrew inputs and messages. Does anyone know the  way?  The current code runs well for English but the final app should based only on Hebrew.

If not what python GUI can do the job?

Roni

Comment: You set the font for the fields to be Hebrew.

Answer (score 0):

This bit of PySimpleGUI code makes a window with Hebrew as text.  All I had to do was install a Hebrew Font (Shlomo semiStam) and specify it in the Text Element.

[image]

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [  [sg.Text('Hebrew Test')],
            [sg.Text('וםושצפּ דּךּתּףּצהןן', font=('Shlomo semiStam', 12))],
            [sg.Button('Exit')]]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)

while True:             # Event Loop
    event, values = window.Read()
    print(event, values)
    if event in (None, 'Exit'):
        break

window.Close()
```